# Fix JSSOR Slider Bug with resizing when disabling CSS-Transforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, jssor

I am using the [JSSOR](http://www.jssor.com/) slider within one of my responsive projects. I was unhappy with the way it implemented responsive resizing because it depended on transform: scale()-concept. So I disabled that behavior (only for the containing div)  by setting

```
#sliderContainer>div {
  transform:none !important;
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
}
```

and set the sizes of `sliderContainer, img` as well as the arrow positions manually with CSS. This will lead to a perfect responsive behaviour. However, there is one bug. When loading in size A and switching to size B (e.g. turning a tablet from portrait into landscape-mode) or resizing a browser window, it will totally screw up the positioning of slides:

[image: JSSOR Slider bug]

I am calling the `jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(e.g. 820)` function properly. But I cannot see any change in the absolute positioning. It looks like the slider totally relies on scale-transformations and does not implement a real, responsive concept.

My question: is there any way to dynamically set the slide width and/or cause a complete re-calculation? Maybe Re-Initiating the slider?

My only solution to this is to manually configure the biggest slide-size:

```
 $SlideWidth: 820, //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels...
```

However, this will lead to sliding with large gaps in the smaller resolutions.

Comment: Very good question. Your concern is reasonable, as I mentioned, we need one more api $ResizeCanvas. I will consider this feature later, but there is a long way to go.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Would it be possible to set the position:absolute; right:xx;- coordinate to the current slider width in the first loop of the slide-animation? This would solve the "offset" problem that I have when using a fixed $SlideWidth parameter and is the easiest bugfix in my opinion. In what function could I change that?

Comment: With $ScaleWidth method, it will always keep aspect ratio. But if you want to make the width smaller and keep height with no change, you can't use the $ScaleWidth method. So, I guess you can make a wrap container, and  place the slider in your container. Thus you can control the size of your container, and control which part of the slider should display.